# Google Translate API translating numbers to their literal string

Tags: google-translate

I'm having an issue where the API is translating the number 15 into the german literal string "fünfzehn" instead of leaving it as a number. It is only the number 15 and no other. It's formatted the same way as other numbers, nothing special about it.

We're sending html, so I had a look at the tags - not the issue either. We'd like to avoid wrapping numbers in a "notranslate" tag since it's only happening for 15.

Has anyone stumbled upon the same thing?